# с++ Вызов функции через указатель

Tags: c++, указатели, c++14

Прошу сначала ознакомиться с кодом:

Bar.h:

```
namespace Foo{
    struct Bar {
        private:
            void MasterUpdate();
            void SlaveUpdate();
        public:
            typedef void (Bar::*pUpdate)();
            Bar(bool master);
            pUpdate Update();
    }
}
```

Bar.cpp

```
void Bar::MasterUpdate(){
    // код...
}

void Bar::SlaveUpdate(){
    // код...
}

void Bar::Bar() {
    if(master) {
        Update = &Bar::MasterUpdate;
    } else {
        Update = &Bar::SlaveUpdate;
    }
}
```

main.cpp

```
#include <Bar.h>
Foo::Bar* bar;

int main() {
    bar = new Foo::Bar(true);
    while (1) {
        // вызов bar->Update();
    }
}
```

1) вызов `bar->Update();` приводит к ошибке:

```
error: must use '.*' or '->*' to call pointer-to-member function in 'bar->Foo::Bar::Update (...)', e.g. '(... ->* bar->Foo::Bar::Update) (...)'`
```

2) Ошибка говорит заменить `->` на `->*` заменяем: `bar->*Update();` - получаем ошибку:

```
error: 'Update' was not declared in this scope
         modbusRtu->*Update()
                            ^
```

3) Поискав в интернете нашёл, что вызов должен быть таким: `(bar->*Update)();`. Пробуем и получаем ошибку похожую на предыдущую.
    error: 'Update' was not declared in this scope
             (modbusRtu->*Update)()
                          ^

Так вот, как вызвать Update у объекта bar?

Comment: В структуре Bar у вас написано pUpdate Update(); - это объявление функции с именем Update возвращающая тип pUpdate, а не указатель на метод. Скобки уберите. А сам вызов будет таким `(bar->*bar->Update)();`

Comment: @DrawnRaccoon, с `pUpdate Update();` это я ошибся пока тут писал. Спасибо огромное ваш ответ работает. Оформите в виде ответа?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
#include <iostream>
#include <functional>

namespace Foo{
    struct Bar {
        private:
            void MasterUpdate()
            {
                std::cout << __FUNCTION__ "\n";
            }
            void SlaveUpdate()
            {
                std::cout << __FUNCTION__ "\n";
            }
        public:
            typedef void (Bar::*pUpdate)();
            Bar(bool master)
            {
                if(master) {
                    Update = &Bar::MasterUpdate;
                } else {
                    Update = &Bar::SlaveUpdate;
                }
            }
            pUpdate Update;
    };
}

int main() {

    {
        Foo::Bar bar(true);
        std::invoke(bar.Update, bar);
    }

    {
        Foo::Bar bar(false);
        std::invoke(bar.Update, bar);
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Вывод:

```
 Foo::Bar::MasterUpdate
 Foo::Bar::SlaveUpdate
```

Comment: О, спасибо! Тоже работает, но разве использование `std::invoke()` это не костыль? :)

Comment: держать  внутри класса указатель на функцию_член этого же класса, дело бессмысленное

Comment: @GoodSimon, `invoke` не может быть костылём, это отличная функция. Её использование может быть не очень оправдано в таком простом случае, но и проблем это никаких не порождает. Поэтому почему бы и нет?